# Regex - match everything but this pattern (and first and last)

Tags: regex, dns

I am trying to adjust the pattern of DNS data to match something that looks like a DNS address. In this case I have a string that looks like this.

```
(19)espnfivethirtyeight(5)files(9)wordpress(3)com(0)
```

I would like  to change that to an actual DNS name, as follows:

```
espnfivethirtyeight.files.wordpress.com
```

Is there a regex expression that would be able to do this?

Comment: What regex flavor are you using and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done in two steps.

1. Use this regex and replace with nothing.

   `^\(\d+\)|\(\d+\)$` This will replace the first and last `(number)` with empty string. <kbd>**[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/kE6dS2/1)**</kbd>
2. Use this regex and replace with a dot.

   `\(\d+\)`  This will replace every occurrence of `(number)` with dot. <kbd>**[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/iR6kF0/1)**</kbd>

Comment: This was for a Splunk installation and field extraction / replacement in DNS. I believe Python is the regex they leverage. This answer gave me plenty to go on. There is an answer on Splunk Answers for this question as well.

Comment: @theGlitchKing: You may as well post that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no indication of regex environment. I'm assuming it's python.

```
import re

data = "(19)espnfivethirtyeight(5)files(9)wordpress(3)com(0)"
rx = re.compile(r"\(\d+\)")

print('.'.join([x for x in rx.split(data) if x!='']))
```

based on input string, it will print:

```
espnfivethirtyeight.files.wordpress.com
```